# Thread synchronization and setting thread's priority

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi, tcp

I have one sender thread and 40 worker threads. There is a single queue. All of the 40 threads write to the queue and the sender thread periodically reads from the shared queue and sends the data read over a tcp socket (say after every 1 sec, the sender thread must read data from the queue and send it over the socket). I have a question here:

1. If any of the 40 threads is in the critical section and all other threads are also waiting to enter the critical section and at the same time 1 sec timer is up and I want to ignore the requests of all other threads to enter the critical section, and the Sender thread must be given priority now and must be given the critical section.

In other words I want to set the priority of sender thread to 1 i.e. when sender thread calls EnterCriticalSection() then, all other threads that are waiting to enter critical section must be ignored and as soon as the critical section gets free, it must be given to the sender thread.
Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You can not achieve it by using just priority, because if any of worker thread is  holding a lock then priority can not force them to free it. Here is one implementation I can think off..

As soon as the sender thread will wake up after 1 sec duration it will send a signal to the worker process. And in the signal handler free the lock that is held by the workers(I guess a binary semaphore would be good here, so put it's value to 0 in the signal handler), so whatever worker thread will try to access it will get blocked. At sender side send all the packets and at the end again set semaphore back to 1.

This is one implementation, you can think think your own like that but eventually it should work .:)

Answer (score 1):

You likely just want some variant of a reader-writer lock. And probably just a plain Win32 critical section lock is all that is needed.

Here's why.  The operations in the critical section, append data to a queue (or reading from the queue), is a non-blocking operation. In other words, no operation on the queue will take longer than a fraction of a millisecond.  If you use the [Windows critical section lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441183/thread-synchronization-and-setting-threads-priority) (EnterCriticalSection, LeaveCriticalSection), fairness is guaranteed to threads waiting to enter the CS (I'm fairly certain of this).

So if all 40 writer threads need to enter the CS to append to the queue, that shouldn't take more than a millisecond or two for the reader thread to wait it's turn to acquire the lock.  This is of course assuming that writer threads are only copying memory a queue and are not doing any long blocking I/O operations while having acquired the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps in solving your problem http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getschedparam.3.html

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions to Your issue lies in The way Threads are implemented in Linux. Try and have a Mutex. Let your Sender thread create a named FIFO (using `mkfifo()` call), And, when you create say 40 worker threads, in their respective functions, make them create a named fifo for receiving. Whenever your Sender thread wants to communicate with one of your Worker thread, use `open()` call to open the worker_fifo and write onto it, close it. But When you have things like a User-Client Application thing, Whenever you open a fifo, put a Mutex Lock, do whatever you want (read/write) and Unlock the Mutex when you are done with it.